# Strange runtime exception on Android 4.4.4

Tags: java, android, exception

I've got this strange stack trace from Flurry Analytics and I have no idea where it comes from. All the classes are from android system and not a single line that tells me where it comes from.

This error happened 3 times on a same device with android 4.4.4

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2865)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3455)
android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2823)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2865)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This is usually related to a `NullPointerException` in the extras of an Activity. But there it seems like your application is not involved. Unless you provide more information on how and when this happens, this look like Android-internal bug to me.

Comment: Where is the classname and exception message for the nested exception?

Comment: Thanks @shkschneider, wish I had more info.

Comment: @user1806860 does your application crash? do you have reasons to believe this is related to Flurry?

Comment: @StephenC, this is whole stack.

Comment: @shkschneider, it is not related to Flurry. It's came from Flurry error trace system. If application crashes, Flurry writes report, just like Google supposed to.

Comment: Im having the same issue with the same stack trace in flurry. in my case it is when im starting a ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent from a DialogFragment (startActivityForResult). im taking the picture and when im supposed to return to the calling fragment the app crashes. i believe this has something to do with the OS killing the background activity/fragments to save memory. in my fragment's onActivityResult im using an instance of the activity (initialized on onAttach) to call a method. I think that because this instance is now cleared the exception above happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem here seems to be that Flurry error reporting is *leaving out* important information.

Anyhow, this is where I think the exception is coming from:

```
private void deliverResults(ActivityClientRecord r, List<ResultInfo> results) {
    final int N = results.size();
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        ResultInfo ri = results.get(i);
        try {
            if (ri.mData != null) {
                ri.mData.setExtrasClassLoader(r.activity.getClassLoader());
            }
            if (DEBUG_RESULTS) Slog.v(TAG,
                    "Delivering result to activity " + r + " : " + ri);
            r.activity.dispatchActivityResult(ri.mResultWho,
                    ri.mRequestCode, ri.mResultCode, ri.mData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!mInstrumentation.onException(r.activity, e)) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Failure delivering result " + ri + " to activity "
                        + r.intent.getComponent().toShortString()
                        + ": " + e.toString(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(This code isn't from Android 4.4.4, but this particular method is identical in the versions I looked at ...)

It would seem that `deliverResults` is catching some exception it got further up the stack, and wrapping / resthoring it as a `RuntimeException`.  At the point that the exception is constructed, it has a message, and `cause`.  Whatever is generating the stacktrace has removed that information, and that is going to make diagnosis hard.

Comment: Thank @StephenC, you are right, just got a full trace from a Google Play. Now it looks solvable.

Comment: @user1806860 can you share your solution (and problem). im having the same exception.

Comment: @AsafK, it is something unrelated - Flurry's stack trace I posted was not complete, there where more lines on top of `deliverResults()`, which are related only to my project. If you got the same problem, than you need a full trace anyway.

Comment: @user1806860 I undestand that. but since im strugling to solve my problem, even though i have a specific idea to where this coming from, i was wondering what was your problem and solution. Can you take a look at the last comment to your question i posted and let me know if this is something similar to what you're having ?

Comment: It is something similar. In my case I open image loading activity and I do believe that calling activity is killed and than recreated, but without some chunks of data. This might be the solution http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject